# UIView Subview don't show up when the frame is set manually

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I want to set the frame of a subview manually.
So I just create a CGRect with CGRectMake and use the new CGRect for the frame of the subview. The problem is that the subview don't show up.
When I just use the view.bounds property of the parent view and assign this as frame to the subview then everything shows up.
I also ensured that the frame is in the displayed area.

```
frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100);
[self.view addSubview:[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame]];
```

Comment: Could you share the code. Also i hope you have added your subView to main UIView.

Comment: Yes I add the subview to the view.

Comment: The subview's frame is probably not in bounds of parent view. Is this in a UIScrollView?

Comment: Just to make sure can you add one UIButton / UILabel to subview and check.

Comment: Yes the subview is in the bounds of the parent view. I also can add a button to the view. I will recheck my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good way to set subview's frame is

```
   subview.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 
        CGRectGetWidth(self.view.bounds), 
        CGRectGetHeight(self.view.bounds));
```

Refer to [link](http://ashfurrow.com/blog/you-probably-dont-understand-frames-and-bounds/)

All the values less than CGRectGetWidth(self.view.bounds) & CGRectGetHeight(self.view.bounds) should work fine

Answer (score 1):

The code in your question will create a view to which you have no reference. This means it has no background colour, contents or other means to see it, and you have no means to set it. You've added the view, but it is invisible.

Create and configure the view first, assigning it to a local variable, before adding it as a subview. As part of this configuration, give the view a background colour or some subviews.

Comment: But my parent view has a black background color. So I should at least see a white space.

Comment: In iOS 7 I think the default background colour is clear.